# Better way to compute this definite piecewise integral

Tags: definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, riemann-sum, fractional-part

I have to find the value of $$I = \int_0 ^{10} [x]^3\{x\}dx$$

Where $[x]= $greatest integer less than or equal to$ x $(the greatest integer function or the floor function)

And $\{x\}= $fractional part of $x $

So I began as follows:

We know, $x=[x]+\{x\}$ which gives us $\{x\}=x-[x]$

Now, I get, $$I = \int_0 ^{10} [x]^3 xdx-\int_0 ^{10} [x]^4dx$$, and then I could go on to evaluate it by breaking it down at integral points $1,2,3,....,10$ and then compute the value. But that seems pretty hard to do by hand, atleast by my method. Is there a more easier/less calculation intensive way to do this? The answer given is $\frac{2025}{2}$

EDIT: Computing $$I= \int_0 ^{10}[x]^3\{x\}dx$$ I get, $$I = 0 + 1^3\int_1 ^2\{x\}dx + 2^3\int_2 ^3\{x\}dx+...+9^3\int_9 ^{10}\{x\}dx$$

So can I just write $$\int_1 ^2\{x\}dx=\int_2 ^3\{x\}dx=...=\int_9 ^{10}\{x\}dx=\int_0 ^1\{x\}dx$$ and then go from there?

Comment: Why not just split the integral into $$\int\limits_0^10^3x+\int\limits_1^21^3x+\ldots+\int\limits_9^{10}9^3x$$

Comment: @DonThousand $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$ and is not equal to $x$ in the interval $1$ to $2$ or any other interval except $(0,1)$....in the interval 1 to 2 it is equal to $(x-1)$....sorry I didn't notice the error in the MathJax in my question

Comment: That's fine, just multiply the sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^9k^3$ by $\frac12$ since $\int\limits_0^1x=\frac12$.

Comment: @DonThousand Yes I decided from the options given in my book that the answer would have to be that but idk exactly why it works? Because in the interval $(1,2)$ we still have the $\int_1 ^2 xdx$ which isn't equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ I would appreciate an explanation of why that exactly works

Comment: As you said, the integral isn't over $x$, it's over the fractional part of $x$, which is equivalent to $\int_0^1x$.

Comment: @DonThousand The integral is still with respect to $dx$ though?

Comment: Yes... not sure why that's relevant.,

Comment: @DonThousand I added an edit. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks, I've understood it clearly now.

Answer (score 2):

Write the integral as a sum of integrals over intervals $(n, n+1)$:
$$\int_0^{10}[x]^3\{x\}dx=\sum_{n=0}^9\int_{n}^{n+1}[x]^3\{x\}dx$$
Now in these intervals $[x]=n$ and $\{x\}=x-n$. So we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^9\int_{n}^{n+1}n^3(x-n)dx=\sum_{n=0}^9\left(n^3\frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{2}-n^4(n+1-n)\right)=\sum_{n=0}^9\frac{n^3}2=\frac{2025}2$$